# Match the first part of lines against a fixed string and count unique values in the second part

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, uniq

`$var` contains thousands of lines with the following format:

```
./abc bbd xyh doc
./docs 2019 abc docx
./docs 2019 abc docx
./docs 2019 abc ppt
./docs 2019 abc ppt
./docs 2019 abc xls
./docs 2019 abc def docx
./docs 2019 abc/def docx
./bdg/aabc/dd efgh 2018 doc
. xls
. pptx
./aax bcd/def/gfhe ttp/five ppt
```

Last column represents an `extension` of a file and everything else (from the beginning of each line, until the very last whitespace character) is `basename` (path) of a corresponding file.

There's a while loop that generates values for `$path` which contains a testing `basename` (path) and my goal is to remove all lines from `$var` that don't match `$path` starting form the beginning of the line until the very last whitespace (excluding the last column). Furthermore, I would like to print only the corresponding extensions (as `| sort | uniq -c`).

For example, if during an iteration from the while loop we send `path="./docs 2019 abc"`, the output should be **the fastest way** to achieve the following:

```
2 docx
2 ppt
1 xls
```

This is what I ended up with, but the output is **wrong** - it prints basenames, instead of extensions and it's pretty slow for each iteration:

```
printf "echo -e \"%s\" | awk '{\$NF=\"\";} ( \$0 ~ /%s/ )' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -nr" "${var}" "${path//\//\\/}" | bash
```

Outputs:

```
2 ./docs 2019 abc
2 ./docs 2019 abc
1 ./docs 2019 abc
```

Comment: `$var contains thousands of lines` is a bad start to any problem. Why do you have a scalar variable containing thousands of lines? There's almost certainly some earlier step in your code that should be fixed so you're not in this situation.

Comment: @EdMorton: My thoughts exactly. `$var` is an output of quite complicated `find` command. To avoid a nesting of such complicated `find` for all subdirectories, I formed that `$var` that contains the entire output. What would be a better way to do this?

P.S. Even recursive (nested) `find -maxdepth 1` for each subdir is faster than this imho.

Comment: How about saving them into a temporary file?

Comment: @oguzismail: That could be done. Do you think that approach would be the fastest way to do it properly?

Comment: Can't say yes without seeing the task for its entirety

Comment: @oguzismail: I will put the code on Github and will share the link here, so you can check. Basically, I'm fiddling with the idea to build a tool that would be a substitute for `du --filter` in a more informative way, which doesn't exist yet as a parameter. Actually I want to be able to filter out just certain extensions and print the results for each subdirectory. The script will be entirely open source.

Comment: @oguzismail: https://github.com/madjoe/wii/blob/master/wii.sh  
You can find my script there to be able to understand the scope. What I'm trying to achieve is to avoid using line #230 from the script and utilize values from a variable `$summary` (presented here as `$var`, same structure). This is my very first bash code and there are probably many things I could improve, so feel free to contribute if you'd like. :)

Comment: I further investigated the issue to see if switching to using files instead of storing large amount of data in a variable. It seems there are no limits for how much data can a bash variable hold, except whatever is set by the OS. However, I could use `mkfifo` and if `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` mount, and it often is, then it's going to use memory anyway. Hm.. It seems that performance wise I'm not doing anything wrong here (storing large amount of data in a variable)? The only serious bottle neck seems to be sorting it multiple times, but @oguzismail already provided a few workarounds for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ path='./docs 2019 abc'
$ grep -Pox "\Q$path\E\s\K\S+" <<< ${var} | sort | uniq -c
      2 docx
      2 ppt
      1 xls
```

This uses a [PCRE](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and thus requires [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

---

With GNU awk it'd be:

```
$ cat prog.awk
gensub(/\s\S+$/, "", 1) == path {
  cnt[$NF]++
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
  for (ext in cnt) {
    print cnt[ext], ext
  }
}
```

```
$ gawk -v path='./docs 2019 abc' -f prog.awk <<< ${var}
2 docx
2 ppt
1 xls
```

This approach would probably be faster than the former as it doesn't spawn `sort` and `uniq`.

---

Just in case none of the tools mentioned above is available, here is a portable solution:

```
$ cat prog.awk
{
  ext = $NF
  sub(/[[:space:]][^[:space:]]+$/, "")
  if ($0 == path)
    cnt[ext]++
}
END {
  for (ext in cnt)
    print cnt[ext], ext
}
```

```
$ awk -v path='./docs 2019 abc' -f prog.awk <<< ${var} | sort -k1nr
2 docx
2 ppt
1 xls
```

---

Note that all these heavily rely on your description of the input and doesn't handle any edge cases you might have missed.